Где здесь грамматическая основа?

Прошло около часа.

В этом предложении же есть сказуемое «прошло», но есть ли тут подлежащее??

It's a one-member sentence (односоставное предложение), more specifically, an impersonal sentence (безличное предложение).
It doesn't have a subject.
Sentences like this usually describe a state or an action that develop without any explicit agent:


Светает
Его ударило током
Тут не пройти


etc.

Не обязательно в русском языке, чтобы в каждом предложении было подлежащее. Рассматривайте это (целое) предложение: Холодно.
